# Joining multiple tables with one producing more results

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've got three tables:

```
Info:
| article_id | title          | author              | rating     | num_comments |
|------------|----------------|---------------------|------------|--------------|
| 1          | a title        | an author           | 3.5        | 2            |
| 2          | another title  | a different author  | 2          | 0            |


Articles:
| article_id | text             |
|------------|------------------|
| 1          | longish text...  |
| 2          | more text...     |


Comments:
|comment_id | article_id | name        | comment    | date_added |
|-----------|------------|-------------|------------|------------|
| 1         | 1          | this name   | first !    | 2013-10-25 |
| 2         | 1          | that name   | bla        | 2013-10-26 |
```

I can retrieve data from the first two without a problem with:

```
    SELECT Info.*, Articles.text 
    FROM Info
    JOIN Articles
    ON Info.article_id = Articles.article_id
    WHERE article_id = :article_id
```

But now I want to grab the rows that match from the third table, sort them by date and preferably output them into a multi-dimensional array.
Is this even possible with one query ?

So the desired result for `article_id = 1` should look like:

```
    array { 
            [article_id] => 1,
            [title] => a title,
            [author] => an author,
            [rating] => 3.5,
            [num_comments] => 2,
            [text] => longish text...,
            [comments] => array {
                                  [1] => array {
                                                 [comment_id] => 1,
                                                 [name] => this name,
                                                 [comment] => first !,
                                                 [date_added] => 2013-10-25
                                  [2] => array {
                                                 [comment_id] => 2,
                                                 [name] => that name,
                                                 [comment] => bla,
                                                 [date_added] => 2013-10-26
                                                }
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a LEFT JOIN in order to get the results from articles even when you don't have comments:

```
SELECT i.*, a.text, c.*
FROM Info i
INNER JOIN Articles a ON Info.article_id = Articles.article_id
LEFT JOIN Comments c ON c.article_id = a.article_id
WHERE a.artice_id = :article_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that produce a result for every comment ?  I edited my question a bit, because I think I wasn't clear about the desired result.

Comment: In one query, that's the closest to what you want that you can achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another join statement and join the third table

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this

```
SELECT * FROM Articles
  JOIN Info ON Articles.id = Info.article_id
  JOIN Comments ON Info.article_id = Comments.article_id WHERE Comments.article_id = :article_id
```